# HiveQL: Select value of column paired with Max(value) of another column

Tags: hive, hiveql

Let´s assume i have this table

```
Date         Department   Value
2017-01-02    A            30
2017-01-02    B            60
2017-01-02    C            10
2017-01-02    D            40
2017-01-03    C            20
2017-01-03    D            150
2017-01-03    E            100
2017-01-03    F            20
...
```

And i want to get the department which have a higher 'value' each day

Which would result in

```
Date          Department   Value
2017-01-02    B            60
2017-01-03    D            150
```

How could i achieve this?

Comment: I have posted an answer using RANK that will solve your issue. You can also use the DENSE_RANK, ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Base data:

```
hive> create table tx1(date1 date,department string,value int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
OK
Time taken: 1.172 seconds
hive> load data local inpath '/home/vivekanand/vivek/hive/test.dat' into table tx1;
Loading data to table default.tx1
OK
Time taken: 0.727 seconds
hive> select * from tx1;
OK
2017-01-02  A   30
2017-01-02  B   60
2017-01-02  C   10
2017-01-02  D   40
2017-01-03  C   20
2017-01-03  D   150
2017-01-03  E   100
2017-01-03  F   20
Time taken: 1.89 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```

You can use the analytical function here as below:

```
select date1,department,value
from(select date1,department,value,rank() over(partition by date1 order by value desc) f from tx1) k
where f=1;
```

Output:

```
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
2017-01-02  B   60
2017-01-03  D   150
Time taken: 1.569 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: That was nice! Also to add, if we use rank() it would put all departments with the same 'top' value at same date. In order to only get one of them, it would be as easy as using row_number(), so that we avoid having more than one row for the same date.

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Break problem in two parts first get max value by date ie [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression).

Join result set with base table and get desired result

ie

```
  with  temp as (
          select Date ,max(value) as value
          from tableName group by Date
  )
  selct a.Date  ,  a.Department ,a.Value 
      from tableName a join temp b
      on a.Date=b.Date 
      and a.value=b.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rank()` analytic function. `rank()` will assign 1 to rows with higher value per day.

```
select Date, Department, Value
from
(
select a.Date, a.Department, a.Value,
       rank() over(partition by a.Date order by a.Value desc) as rnk
  from tableName a
)s
where rnk=1
;
```